# Accessing values from a joined query from Doctrine with Twig

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, doctrine-query

I have a problem with accessing the values from a joined query. I built a query in a Repository that joins/left joins tables.

To make the following code a bit understandable: I have an appointment. This appointment is part of an event and event is part of an event group. An event group has participants. In real life, this means that every participant of an event is also a participant of an appointment. For example, there is a training centre. This centre has different training courses (running, lifting...). Each course has different events for different groups (like group A always Monday and Friday and group B always Tuesday and Thursday). So you could take part in running in group A. And Appointments are the correct date and time for each group.

Now I want all the appointments from one person. So my query looks like this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->leftJoin('a.event', 'event')
    ->leftJoin('event.eventgroup', 'eventgroup')
    ->innerJoin('event.participants', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $user->getId())
;

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

If I look in doctrine, I also get the correct results, when run the processed query in mysql. But if I want to access a value from the table in my twig file it doesn't work.

```
{% for appointment in appointments|default(false) %}
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="livemode.html">
            <span class="col-md-4">{{ appointment.getEventGroup() }}&emsp;<span class="tag tag-default">{{ appointment.getName() }}</span></span>
             <span class="col-md-4">{{ appointment.getTopicBlock().getName() }}</span>
            <span>{{ appointment.getDate()|date("d.m.Y") }}&emsp;09:30 Uhr</span>
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

The entities and methods are correct. Other queries work fine. But with this one, I get a Symfony error that the method is not correct. If I don't use the values and the loop, I get 4 times the html elements. This is also the correct amount of the results. Is there maybe a problem with the inner join? Because with that I dont only just link the id's to other entities in the db, but join them multiple times to an event? Can I access the values in another way?

Comment: Is it too late to add another answer? Isouza's might work, but I see what you are doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entity is properly mapped, you should be able to access the relationships and properties simply by accessing them directly:

```
{% for appointment in appointments|default(false) %}
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="livemode.html">
            <span class="col-md-4">{{ appointment.eventGroup }} <span class="tag tag-default">{{ appointment.name }}</span></span>
             <span class="col-md-4">{{ appointment.topicBlock.name }}</span>
            <span>{{ appointment.date|date("d.m.Y") }} 09:30 Uhr</span>
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This assumes that the `Appointment` entity has the `EventGroup` relationship mapped and also have a getter method for that.

If it doesn't work, you could add the code for your entities and I edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I really don't know whyI didn't do this myself. Nothing had changed from previous practice. Might be that I am a bit tired. I sat for more than 1 hour in front of this ;D  But I had to write `appointment.event.eventgroup.getName()` because I have of course no direct access from `appointment` to `eventgroup` because `event` is between them and then get the `name` attribute by calling `getName()`